# Contains method ignoring case

Tags: c#, .net

I have two string arrays which I need to compare for the like strings.

```
string[] f1 = {"Ann", "mam", "far", "aBc"};
string[] f2 = {"ann", "nom", "far", "abc"};

Parallel.ForEach(f1, currenFile =>
{
    if (f2.Contains(currenFile, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("matchfound"+currenFile);
    }
});
```

I am trying to see if f2 contains the word from f1 ignoring case. However intelisense has error on "StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase" Saying

> argument type System.StringComparission is not assignable to parameter type Systems.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer

Please let me know how can i fix this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Comment: Not the same.  That is looking for a string in a string.  Not a string in a string[] array.

Comment: Unless one is blind this is not same question. It looks like some people have trigger happy fingers to just keep making everything duplicate

Comment: Your if statement looks for a string in a string, does it not? Sure you added the parallel foreach, but the essential question still seems to be the same to me. As an aside, I came up across that question while researching an answer to yours, so I'm not "trigger happy" at all, I found a question that asks the same thing (IMHO) with highly upvoted answers, and so marked this as a duplicate.

Comment: I did not notice that f2 was an array, I apologize for the mistake. I have retracted my close vote (it was an honest mistake though :) ). The answers will be similar, but it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @BradleyDotNet I understand some times i do same too. Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for speed I would so use consider HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Comment: @Blam speed is critical as the real data is very large. Thanks will try it out.

Comment: You may get a 10x improvement in speed.  HashSet.Contains is O(1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed that error in VS2013 by using

```
StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
```

instead of

```
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
```

Alternatively, you could try the following:

```
string[] f1 = { "Ann", "mam", "far", "aBc" };
string[] f2 = { "ann", "nom", "far", "abc" };
Parallel.ForEach(f1, currentFile =>
{
    if (f2.Any(comparisonFile => String.Compare(currentFile, comparisonFile, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("matchfound" + currentFile);
    }
});
```

Comment: @BradleyDotNET that is because it is not a duplicate

Comment: @J. Davidson: I have your exact code with this one replacement in my Visual Studio browser right now and it compiles. Are you sure you are using StringComparer instead of StringComparison?

Comment: @VP Well what version of .Net framework are you using? Is it on 4.5? I am on vs2012 and 4.5.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET What part of looking for a string within a string is different than looking for a string in a string[] array is not clear?  My name has an 'la' in it by my name is not 'la'.  The duplicate is string and this is string[].  Do you know what an array is?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET f2 is an array.  There is no array in that so called duplicate.

Comment: @J.Davidson MSDN says it works in 4.5, we are using VS2013 though to answer your question. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer(v=vs.110).aspx and see if it gives you anything.

Comment: @Blam, I did not fully process the second array decleration, you are correct that this question is subtly different. Thank you for the effort to correct my mistake.

Comment: @VP Thanks did a clean re-build and made the changes its working fine.

Comment: @J.Davidson Glad to hear it